# Navigation component, popping back to another modules Destination

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a multi module project that uses Navigation Component to navigate between Fragments. This means that in order to get to another module, I have to launch a DeepLink using `findNavController().navigate(NavDeepLinkRequest, NavOptions)`. When it comes time to log out of the application, I need to pop the back stack inclusive to a Destination in another module that is not visible to that module. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue and I believe Google doesn't support it by default using Navigation Component (which is sad). However I managed to do it in a bit hacky way (but it works) using old friend `getIdentifier`.

In your `Fragment` you may have a navigation request like this:

```
val navigateToOtherModuleRequest = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
    .fromUri("yourapp://othermoduledestination".toUri())
    .build()
```

Then get the resource id you need to pop-up to using `getIdentifier()` (it can be `Fragment` id or in my case `nav graph` id):

```
val homeNavGraphResourceId = resources.getIdentifier(
    "home_nav_graph",
    "id",
    requireContext().packageName
)
```

Define `navigationOptions` like this:

```
val navigationOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
    .setPopUpTo(
        destinationId = homeNavGraphResourceId,
        inclusive = true
    )
    .build()
```

And navigate using

```
findNavController().navigate(
    navigateToOtherModuleRequest,
    navigationOptions
)
```

Hope this will help!